# Register MS-Word dll

Tags: dll, vb6, ms-word

I have an application in vb6 that creates `word documents` using objects like

```
Word.Application , Word.Document, Word.Range
```

To do so I need to have the MS-Office installed on my computer, or an error is fired because the missing `.DLL`. Is there a way to download and register this `dll` without instaling the whole `MS-Office`? I know it sounds wierd like "Why you want to generate a word document without ms-word". But I need this to make some tests here. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Office Automation is only possible if the Office product is installed on the system. (You can't automate something that isn't there to be automated.)

If you want to use Word automation, you have to install Word. You might be able to find a third-party solution that will create Word documents directly (without actually using Word), but you'd need to use a search engine to locate one.